# How can I convert an image's pixel color information into numbers and store it in a CSV?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, computer-vision, object-comparison

How do I extract the pixel color information in an image into numbers and store them in a CSV file? These numbers should all go into 1 row and multiple columns. If the image is 50*50 then there should be only 1 row and 2500 columns containing the pixel color information. How can I achieve this in Python? Please advice.

I found the code which was,

```
pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size
pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in xrange(height)]
```

But I want this list in a single row and multiple columns as my svm expects it in that format for training the images.

The output should look like below given since this is a grey scale image,
2 3 253...

where 2 is the color of the 1st pixel and 3 is the color of the 2nd pixel and 253 is the color of 3rd etc. 2 will be in 1st cell of the 1st row and 3 in 2nd cell and 253 in 3rd cell and so on. But the whole image pixels will be in this row. So if its a 50*50 picture there will be 2500 columns/cells containing the pixel values as mentioned above.

Comment: You should post the code you've written so far as well as an explanation for why you would want a 2500 column csv. Also you could be clearer about what colour information you want, RGB, RGBA, CMYK?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I edited the question. I need the code parts related to CSV which I couldn't find in that quesstion. Please remove the duplicate mark. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Edited the question. I need it in that format for the SVM. Please advice.

Comment: How is it supposed to look? Is it `rgb(1,255,45),rgb(255,255,225)...2500 times` or `#FFAE32,#01DD87...2500 times` or what? Please frame your question with all the information neededd.

Comment: There are no commas in `2 3 253`. Do you mean you want space separated values and not comma separated values (CSV)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to unwind the array (which is a list of lists). You can do this with a double list comprehension:

```
pixels = [i for row in pixels for i in row]
```

If you want to write it to a file with spaces between your values you can do this

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   outfile.write(' '.join([str(i) for i in pixels])
```

Comment: and how can I then write these into individual cells> please help